# Tableau - Embed link into countries

Tags: dictionary, interactive, tableau-api

I have a Tableau Public map which highlights countries for which my organization has publications.

Currently you can only link at entire sheet, but I want to apply the publication URLs to their respective countries, opening them in a new tab on country select.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URLs in your data source, you can create [URL actions](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/actions_url.html) that should give you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, RESOLVED -- > 
I found that initially the links weren't working because they weren't written with https:// (must be secure).

Then I put the URL in the Marks section, deleted its text from the Tooltip, and in Actions... Added a URL action on Select.

This is definitely basic stuff but maybe useful for fellow n00bs :)